# Drag And Drop Files

Tags: java, swing, drag-n-drop

Здравствуйте. К сожалению возникла потребность реализовать Drag And Drop в desktop приложении, на Swing. 
Необходимо перетаскивая файл из FileExplorer(Проводник), на элемент GUI Swing, в принципе не важно на какой, извлекать путь к файлу и записывать в переменную.
Прошу подсказать как!? примером если не сложно:)
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Java приемнике надо реализовать метод `drop()`, где надо распознавать тип сброшенного объекта как `DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor`:

```
public synchronized void drop (DropTargetDropEvent dropTargetDropEvent) {
  try
        {
            Transferable tr = dropTargetDropEvent.getTransferable();
            if (tr.isDataFlavorSupported (DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor))
            {
                dropTargetDropEvent.acceptDrop (
                    DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
                java.util.List fileList = (java.util.List)
                    tr.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                Iterator iterator = fileList.iterator();
                //дальше работаем со списком файлов
            }
        }
}
```

Куда впихивать `drop()` можно понять через [туториал](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html)

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 2):

Так же выкладываю свой вариант, что бы он мог помочь остальным кто ищет и мог просто скопипастить, так как очень долго искал нужный пример, вдруг кому надо :)

```
public class Face extends javax.swing.JFrame {
String filePath;

/**
 * Creates new form Face
 */
public Face() {
    initComponents();
    MyDragDropListener myDragDropListener = new MyDragDropListener();
    new DropTarget(jLabel1, myDragDropListener);

}

class MyDragDropListener implements DropTargetListener {
    private Object MessageBox;

@Override
public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent event) {

    // Accept copy drops
    event.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);

    // Get the transfer which can provide the dropped item data
    Transferable transferable = event.getTransferable();

    // Get the data formats of the dropped item
    DataFlavor[] flavors = transferable.getTransferDataFlavors();

    // Loop through the flavors
    for (DataFlavor flavor : flavors) {

        try {

            // If the drop items are files
            if (flavor.isFlavorJavaFileListType()) {

                // Get all of the dropped files
                List files = (List) transferable.getTransferData(flavor);

                // Loop them through
                for ( Object file : files) {

                    // Print out the file path
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, file);


               }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            // Print out the error stack
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    // Inform that the drop is complete
    event.dropComplete(true);

}

@Override
public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent event) {
}

@Override
public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent event) {
}

@Override
public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent event) {
}

@Override
public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent event) {
}
```